# How do I set the color of the notch on iPhone X in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, iphone-x

I have been testing my application on an iPhone X via iOS Simulator. I would like to know how I can recolour the black notch to the same color as my application theme.

Here's the current implementation:

[image]

How do I change the black bar to blue, matching my theme?

Comment: If your intention is to color the status bar (the area where time and battery indicators are shown) then this question might be of help. I am deleting my current answer as it is not relevant

Comment: Dan, take a look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46318395/detecting-mobile-device-notch/46362263#46362263 Hopefully it'll address your issue (bottom part relates to CSS)

Comment: The answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297291/how-to-set-ios-status-bar-background-color-in-react-native

Answer (score 10):

You can simply use SafeAreaView from react-native new version 51.

```
import {
  ...
  SafeAreaView
} from 'react-native';
class Main extends React.Component {
 render() {
   return (
     <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>
       <App />
     </SafeAreaView>
   )
 }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 ...,
 safeArea: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: '#FF5236'
 }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

See: [How to set iOS status bar background color in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297291/how-to-set-ios-status-bar-background-color-in-react-native)

- For an iPhone X, the increase StatusBarHeightIos from 20 to 30
- I use react-native-device-info to detect device

`import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';`

// getModel: iPhone X
// getDeviceId: iPhone10,3
const ModelIphoneX = 'iPhone X';

// StatusBarHeight is where Carrier info and date display at top
// iPhone X has a cut-out in top of dispaly where sensor package is located.
// For iPhone X increase height so cut-out does not hide text
const StatusBarHeightIos = DeviceInfo.getModel() === ModelIphoneX ? 30 : 20;
const StatusBarHeight = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? StatusBarHeightIos : 0;

Screenshot: iPhone X on left

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed by changing the app launch screen from image assets to a Storyboard, using XCode.